# how to create a table with dynamic rows numbers and cells by php

Tags: php, html

I want to create a table that has dynamic rows () and in each rows has 5 cells (td) .
for example:

```
$rows=mysqli_affected_rows($dbCnn);
```

If for example $rows=7, we should have two tr. first tr has 5 td, and the second tr has two td.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: how can I create this table? how many for it need, and how ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...If for example $rows=7, we should have two tr. first tr has 5 td, and the second tr has two td.

Use `for` loop for this.

```
$rows=mysqli_affected_rows($dbCnn); // for example, $rows = 7;

$counter = 1;
echo "<table><tr>";
for($i = 0; $i < $rows;){
    if($counter % 6 == 0){
        echo "</tr><tr>";
    }else{
        echo "<td> YOUR_VALUE </td>";
        ++$i;
    }
    ++$counter;
}
echo "</tr></table>";
```

[Here's the demo](https://ideone.com/GzawCL)

Comment: @Hamid Glad I could help, cheers! :-) Please mark the answer as *accepted* if it resolved your issue. [How to accept answer on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)